# Unable to call AppDbContext in a SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

Why I'm unable to use `AppDbContext` in a SignalR Hub? There is nothing wrong with the query itself. It works outside of the hub context. The `email` is resolved correctly.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> at lambda_method1325(Closure , QueryContext )
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

My whole idea is whenever the user logs in, to send all undelivered messages to him. Or maybe I'm not supposed to? Perhaps the frontend is supposed to call an endpoint which is going to initially load these undelivered messages from the outbox table as opposed to OnConnectedAsync?

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public sealed class SignalRHub : Hub
{
    readonly ILogger<SignalRHub> _logger;
    readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public SignalRHub(ILogger<SignalRHub> logger, IMediator mediator)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var email = Context.User.GetEmailAddress();
        
        await SendUndeliveredNotificationsAsync(email);

        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    async Task SendUndeliveredNotificationsAsync(string email)
    {
        var undeliveredNotifications = await _mediator.Send(new GetUndeliveredNotificationsForUserQuery(email));
        var tasks = undeliveredNotifications.Select(notificationMessage => _mediator.Send(new SendInAppNotificationCommand(notificationMessage.Id)));
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}

public sealed record GetUndeliveredNotificationsForUserQuery(string Email) : IRequest<IReadOnlyCollection<NotificationMessage>>;

public sealed class GetUndeliveredNotificationsForUserQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetUndeliveredNotificationsForUserQuery, IReadOnlyCollection<NotificationMessage>>
{
    readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

    public GetUndeliveredNotificationsForUserQueryHandler(AppDbContext dbContext) => _dbContext = dbContext;

    public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<NotificationMessage>> Handle(GetUndeliveredNotificationsForUserQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        => await _dbContext.NotificationMessages
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.Notification)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Employee)
            .Where(x => x.Notification.Employee != null && x.Notification.Employee.Email == request.Email && x.DateDelivered == null)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to inject  DbContext instance directly within SignalRHub class constructor? Within the current implementation you are calling DbContext outside of HubContext which causing the issue. Would you kindly try injecting within your HubConstructor? DbContext DI is the considering factor here. Please [`have a look more details in official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, I tried, it's not the MediatR command.

Comment: If you comment this method `Context.User.GetEmailAddress()` does it still throw error?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, yeah. It's the AppDbContext. I think it has something to do with the multi-tenancy. Because if I want to DI AppDbContext in a HostedService, I have to set the tenant. Perhaps the hub needs too?

Comment: Yeah, so far I investigated `AppDbContext` causing the issue and hub also needs that.

Comment: Glad to know that your problem has resolved. Did you injected the `AppDbContext` in hub service?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, yeah. It was caused by the multi-tenancy. I don't get why the AuthorizeAttribute resolves the claims but not the tenant id itself. Because we have that in the token as well. `Context.User.GetTenant()` resolves it. But when I manually set the tenant id, it works fine. I posted the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

Although the claims are resolved from the `AuthorizeAttribute`, the tenant id itself isn't being set.

This is what I ended up doing. What's important is`_dbContext.TenancyContext.Tenant = applicationTenant;`

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public sealed class SignalRHub : Hub
{
    readonly ILogger<SignalRHub> _logger;
    readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

    public SignalRHub(ILogger<SignalRHub> logger, AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    ...

    public async Task GetUndeliveredMessages()
    {
        var email = Context.User.GetEmailAddress();
        var tenant = Context.User.GetTenant();
        
        var applicationTenant = await _dbContext.Tenants.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.NormalizedCanonicalName == tenant);
        
        _dbContext.TenancyContext.Tenant = applicationTenant;
        
        var undeliveredMessages = await _dbContext.NotificationMessages
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.Notification)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Employee)
            .Where(x => x.Notification.Employee != null && x.Notification.Employee.Email == email && x.ChannelType == ChannelType.InApp && x.DateDelivered == null)
            .Select(x => x.MapToResponse())
            .ToListAsync();
            
        await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReceiveUndeliveredMessages", undeliveredMessages);
    }
}
```

Comment: Brat, ti didn't mark it as the answer. Ti should do that